# Why JavaFX Application.launch() takes class as an argument?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I'm new to javaFx and looked a bit into source code and have a question regarding 
Application.launch function that is used to start an app.

Signature looks like this:

```
public static void launch(Class<? extends Application> appClass, String... args)
```

And my question is why it doesn't look like this:

```
 public static void launch(Application app, String... args)
```

What authors try to achieve by taking class as an argument?

Answer (score 5):

Because an instantiation of the `Application` is a complex task which FX developers have to have the control over.

The `Application` instantiation:

- requires "FX toolkit" to be initialized in advance
- differs for the desktop, jnlp and plugin modes
- requires the specific timing
- should be called on the special "launcher" thread
- should trigger the application lifecycle events
- should read the application parameters (from CLI or jnlp file)

Thus you provide only class name to launch and JavaFX do all the work required, including creating an object for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the reason is that this way it more works like it would when you could launch directly through "java my.pkg.MyApp" which you can now in Java8/FX8 because it is on the classpath.

For a definitive answer you'd probably have to ask at the openjfx-mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

The class argument denotes the immediately enclosing class of the method that called launch

Comment: That's true, but my question is why? Why authors prefer parsing stack trace rather than accept user created object?

Comment: Parsing the stack trace??

Answer (score 0):

**Probably**, they are using Reflection under the hood. Something like, get the name of the class as an argument to `launch()` then call the `start()` of that class.

*As with other questions on Stack where people ask what the authors were trying to achieve, we are not privy to the decisions they make.*

Comment: Yes, they do use reflection. I have found this approach to be very useful for the development of your own library for specific types of JavaFX applications where you may end up using delegation and other things in your design while using your own subclass of Application.