# JavaFx - Worker Thread - launch(args)

Tags: javafx-8

I wish to know few things about JavaFx. I am new to JavaFx and learning on my own.

1. JavaFX gui runs on which Thread. I know Event Dispatch Thread was responsible for continuous responsiveness of Swing components regardless of what happens with the application code in background.
2. If the execution of JavaFX begins from start(), why is the main () still placed inside the class with a launch(args) inside it?? I tried finding solution but didnt get any proper explanation. Basically i wish to know the lifecycle of JAvaFx components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaDocs of the [`Application` Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) are very good, for example concerning the life-cycle:

1. Constructs an instance of the specified Application class
2. Calls the init() method
3. Calls the start(javafx.stage.Stage) method
4. Waits for the application to finish, which happens when either of the following occur:

   - the application calls Platform.exit()
   - the last window has been closed and the implicitExit attribute on Platform is true
     Calls the stop() method

The *Threading* topic there should answer your other question.

Regarding the `main` method: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19623520/4219144). A JavaFX Application may be launched on various targets and platforms, not all of them make use of the `main` method.